# Change permission on /usr with a sudo chmod 644 /usr

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, chmod, disaster-recovery

I am a trainee programmer and I have sometimes my head in the clouds..

My collegues were messing with my professional computer with ssh connections. One of them told me that the best way to prevent it was to secure my computer. In order to do this, I accidentally change the permissions on the /usr directory.
What I did just for testing was :

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr
```

Now I can't use my computer anymore! I can't change the permission back since I am not sudo anymore. On my desktop all my applications shutdown.
Is there a way to revert a chmod 644 on /usr?

There is some important work related stuff on this computer and my internship will probably be terminated if I can't recover the access to important files.

Please help !!

Comment: boot from a recovery (or "trial/no-install" - ubuntu, debian etc.pp,) cdrom/usbstick of your choice and mount your fs, then adjust your permissions on /mountpoint/usr. And take away your "friends' "  sudo permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This command need a Sudoers password:

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr
```

So either you have a sudo password and can change the right to this file with:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr
```

Or you friends messed with you...

You can do it by:

adding your self to sudoers on boot...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but i can't do that. First I thought that reboot would fix my problem but since I did that I can't do anything and sudo chmod 755 /usr doesn't work.

Comment: You can add your self to sudoeur like I said in the link, and remove your self from it after everything is corrected...